# Why doesn't max-width take effect?

Tags: html, css

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/xA8rm/

```
<div style="max-width:10px; oveflow:hidden;">
      adwadddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
</div>
```

I expected the `div` to be 10px in width and the characters that don't fit to be hidden.

**Why** isn't that happening?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="max-width:10px; overflow-x:hidden;">
    adwadddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
</div>
```

First, you've misspelled `overflow`.

Second, `max-width` won't work on an `hbox` element (because they are `display:inline` and you can't set widths and heights on inline elements), so I changed it to a `div`. (You could also use an `hbox` and set it to `display:block` instead if you want to.)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xA8rm/13/)**

Answer (score 2):

Change `oveflow: hidden` to `overflow: hidden` (You're missing the R):

http://jsfiddle.net/NYxyc/

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `r`:

```
oveflow:hidden
```

should be:

```
overflow:hidden
```